# Dont know syntax for `current_user` in `if` statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying do display songs which user has contributed to, if the user has contributed to any. I am trying to write a conditional to express:

If the current user has contributed to a song, then loop through them and display the songs in the list.
Else, don't display anything.

Heres the segment of my showpage:

```
   <div class ="col-md-4 transparent" id="my-contributes">
     <h3>Tracks contributed to</h3>
      <div class="list-group" id="contributed_tracks">
        <% @contributed_songs.each do |song| %>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= song.username %> - <%= song.title %></h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
        </a>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Songs#index:

```
def index
  if current_user 
    @songs = current_user.songs.all
  elsif current_user.nil?
    @songs = Song.all
  end
  @title = "MusicApp"
  @contibuted_versions = Version.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  @contributed_songs = []
  @contributed_versions.each do |version|
  @contributed_songs << version.song
end
@contributed_songs.uniq!
end
```

I know that there needs to be an `if` statement with:

```
     <div class="list-group" id="contributed_tracks">
        <% @contributed_songs.each do |song| %>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= song.username %> - <%= song.title %></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
          </a>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

and the `else` containing nothing, I just don't know the syntax for saying `if current_user` has contributed songs.

Comment: Do you mean something like: `if current_user.songs.count > 0`. But if you already have a `@contributed_songs` with the users contributed songs you could also do something like `if @contributed_songs.size > 0`.

Comment: I am seeing that the issue might really lie in my controller. The error i'm getting is `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` and is pointing to the `@contributed_versions.each do |version|` line of the controller. Any tips?

Comment: Ahh yeah, you have a typo `@contibuted_versions` and `@contributed_versions`

Answer (score 0):

```
<% unless @contributed_songs.empty? %>
  <div class ="col-md-4 transparent" id="my-contributes">
    <h3>Tracks contributed to</h3>
    <div class="list-group" id="contributed_tracks">
      <% @contributed_songs.each do |song| %>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= song.username %> - <%= song.title %></h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
      </a>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

to not display anything if there are no contributed songs. `@contributed_songs` should never be `nil` in your implementation (unless you make a typo :p )